# how can i change default date input in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i have a date input form in rails but by default form gets takes input as yyyy-mm-dd. how can i take date input as dd-mm-yyyy format in rails form? here is how date form field look by default.

[default form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFXTs.png)

```
  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :planned_start_date %>
    <%= form.date_select :planned_start_date, class: 'select-date' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :planned_end_date %>
    <%= form.date_select :planned_end_date, class: 'select-date' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :planned_start_date %>
    <%= form.date_select :planned_start_date, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: 'select-date' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :planned_end_date %>
    <%= form.date_select :planned_end_date, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: 'select-date' %>
  </div>
```

API Documentation for `order` option reference can be found [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select#method-i-date_select-label-Options)